# Flutter Firebase Storage error No object exists at the desired reference

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this error every time i run getDownloadURL, i keeps  saying no object exists at the location but I added the images I want to download in

the root and my file extension is correct, I don't know what I'm doing wrong,

here is the full error

```
I/flutter (23569): here is your url https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/posweepay.appspot.com/o/cables.jpg?alt=media&token=829a25e4-becd-416f-9b01-3498a3e79546
I/flutter (23569): found data on cloudstore Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot>'
E/StorageException(23569): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(23569): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(23569):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(23569): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(23569): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(23569):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:434)
E/StorageException(23569):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:451)
E/StorageException(23569):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:442)
E/StorageException(23569):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(23569):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:286)
E/StorageException(23569):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:70)
E/StorageException(23569):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:62)
E/StorageException(23569):  at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:76)
E/StorageException(23569):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/StorageException(23569):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
```

here is my code

```
                                                              printUrl() async {
    Reference ref = 
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('cables.jpg');
       
       var togo = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
    setState(() {
      url =  togo;
    print('here is your url'+url);
    });
    
}
```

these are my rules

```
1
service firebase.storage {
2
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
3
    match /{allPaths=**} {
4
      allow read, write;
5
    }
6
  }
7
}
8
```

​

[image]

Comment: `/cables.jpg' doesn't exists or you have to take a look at the rules you set up

Comment: iv added my rules to the question

Comment: are you sure the file exists?

Comment: i added more info to my question, I have taken a screenshot of my storage to show you the file exists also my code prints out the URLwhich was https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/posweepay.appspot.com/o/cables.jpg?alt=media&token=829a25e4-becd-416f-9b01-3498a3e79546   but still says fle doesn't exist, I don't understand

Comment: what is `duuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuudreeeeeeeeee` in your urls while printing ? do you get this same everytime you print url ?

Comment: i updated my code, but  it was part of my previous code, now its just "this is your url"

Comment: you need to use something like: firebase_storage.UploadTask ut = ref.putFile(file);
    await ut.whenComplete(() => {});

Comment: Pablo reyes is right.

Comment: Why do you need to upload a file if what we want to do is download something from storage?

Comment: pablo's answer was right for me. I needed to add an await to the .putData, before getting the references download url